# Ipad Pro height not aligning with each other

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please show me how to align the height in a uniform manner, please? I am using bootstrap 3 but I am having issues when it comes to tablet devices the columns look like this...

[image: Demo image]

As for my HTML I followed the `container > row > col > box` rule and `col-md-6` for table and `col-lg-4` for large devices. I followed this tutorial to add the following class but still I am having issues with the alignment of height.

```
.row.is-flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row.is-flex > [class*='col-'] {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

/*
* And with max cross-browser enabled.
* Nobody should ever write this by hand. 
* Use a preprocesser with autoprefixing.
*/
.row.is-flex {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row.is-flex > [class*='col-'] {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: could you post your html as well please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS only for ipad

Note: Apply this css on top of block class. I am assuming your top block class is: `.row.is-flex`

```
    .row.is-flex:nth-child(2n+1){ 
        clear:left;    
    }
```

If any query let me know